# Return a list of JSObjectReference in Blazor using JS Interop

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, blazor, blazor-jsinterop

Is it possible to return a list of object references from JS to C#? Currently I do return a list of objects (THREE.js objects) though I am unable to deserialize it into a C# IList or array to get separate IJSObjectReference instances on .NET side. I simply get one IJSObjectReference (logically possible) which is a reference to the JS array itself.

Anyone know if it is possible to deserialize a JS Array into a C# array/list/collection and in this case, for it to contain JSObject references?

This is basically what I am trying to do

```
const myJsFunc () = () => {
    ....
    return [someJsObject, anotherJsObject]
}
```

C# side

```
var objectReferencesArray = js.Invoke<IJSInProcessObjectReference[]>("myJsFunc", ...);
```

or

```
var objectReferencesArray = js.Invoke<IList<IJSInProcessObjectReference>>("myJsFunc", ...);
```

neither work. I am only able to get ONE object ref which is for the array itself.

EDIT: Still interested in hearing suggestions on this but as an update I can say that I chose to simply return the list as its own IJSInProcessObjectReference and then when I pass it back to JS, destruct it and handle it that way.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot directly return a list of `IJSObjectReference` instead you can do like this

js Code

```
const myJsFunc = () => {
    return [JSON.stringify(someJsObject), JSON.stringify(anotherJsObject)];
}
```

c# Code

```
var jsonStringArray = js.Invoke<string[]>("myJsFunc", ...);
var objectReferencesList = new List<IJSObjectReference>();

foreach (var jsonString in jsonStringArray)
{
    var objectRef = await js.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("JSON.parse", jsonString);
    objectReferencesList.Add(objectRef);
}
```

this way u can get a list from JS

Comment: Hmm this kind of defeats the purpose of my project as I am trying to reduce the amount of JSInterop calls I need in my code. If I need to call into JS to parse the objects to IJSobjects back then there is no real difference from (in my case) just calling my function twice and returning the values separately.. Is there no known way to return a list or array in one call?

Answer (score 0):

#### Updated 2024-04-04

I now have 2 ways. The original answer, now answer 2, used a library I wrote. The new answer, answer 1, does not require any additional libraries and only takes a few minor changes.

## Answer 1

- In Javascript, wrap each object in the array using `DotNet.createJSObjectReference()` which returns a simple object. Ex. `{ __jsObjectId: 1 }`
- Send the array of `__jsObjectId` values to Blazor as the return value of your method as a `long[]`
- In Blazor, you can then create an `IJSInProcessObjectReference[]` using the `long[]` and a little reflection.

#### Code

Javascript side:

```js
const myJsFunc = () => {
    // create a object reference for each and return an array of the ids
    return [window, window, null].map(o => o === null || o === void 0 ? -1 : DotNet.createJSObjectReference(o).__jsObjectId);
}
```

C# side:

```cs
// get the class Type used for IJSInProcessObjectReference
Type WebAssemblyJSObjectReferenceType = typeof(Microsoft.JSInterop.WebAssembly.WebAssemblyJSRuntime).Assembly.GetType("Microsoft.JSInterop.WebAssembly.WebAssemblyJSObjectReference")!;
// convert the object ids into array of IJSInProcessObjectReference
IJSInProcessObjectReference[]? objectReferencesArray = js.Invoke<long[]?>("myJsFunc")?.Select(id => 
 id < 0 ? null : (IJSInProcessObjectReference)Activator.CreateInstance(WebAssemblyJSObjectReferenceType, js, id)!).ToArray();
```

This is a bare min work up. You should cache the WebAssemblyJSObjectReference type by setting it to a static variable.

## Answer 2

Using Nuget package [SpawnDev.BlazorJS](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SpawnDev.BlazorJS):
Program.cs

```cs
// Inject and init BlazorJSRuntime
builder.Services.AddBlazorJSRuntime();
```

Razor page (for example)

```cs
[Inject]
BlazorJSRuntime JS { get; set; }

...

var objectReferencesArray = JS.Call<IJSInProcessObjectReference[]>("myJsFunc", arg1, arg2, ...);
```

GitHub Repo: [SpawnDev.BlazorJS](https://github.com/LostBeard/SpawnDev.BlazorJS)

[Documentation](https://lostbeard.github.io/blazorjs-docs/)

SpawnDev.BlazorJS is a full Javascript interop library that contains over 300 Javascript types allowing complete access to the Javascript environment in Blazor WASM.

I am the author of SpawnDev.BlazorJS.
[image: NuGet]